# ¿En java swing, como se ejecuta codigo al cerrar una pestaña?

Tags: java, java-swing, ventana

Tengo un programa en java, que es una interfaz hecha con **swing**, y quiero que al cerrarse me ejecute una linea de código.
Ahora mismo tengo una clase que me crea la pestaña asi:

```
package graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class AudioFrame extends JFrame{

public AudioLayer layer;

public AudioFrame(){

    setTitle("Comunicaciones orales");

    setBounds(400, 200, 600, 300);

    layer = new AudioLayer();

    add(layer);

    setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Y otra clase llamada **AudioLayer**, donde esta la interfaz programada.
Pero no encuentro la forma de hacer que cuando se cierre la pestaña ejecute una linea de código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la documentacion oficial de java informa que existe una clase llamada WindowsListener el cual puedes adicionar a tu JFrame para que escuche cuando cierres la ventana. Aqui esta el [Enlace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent)).

Utilizo la clase WindowsAdapter para evitar implementar todos los metodos de la interfaz WindowsListener y asi solo sobrescribir el metodo cuando cierre la ventana.

Quedaria algo asi:

```
  miFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            //Hacer lo que yo quiero
            System.out.println("Estoy cerrando");
        }
 });
```

De todas formas te dejo este [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html) con ejemplos propios de Oracle

Comment: Gracias, la respuesta me ha sido útil para lo que quería.